# What is the {L} Unicode category?

Tags: java, regex, unicode, character-properties

I came across some regular expressions that contain `[^\\p{L}]`. I understand that this is using some form of a Unicode category, but when I checked [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Character.html#unicode_categories), I found only the following "L" categories:

```
Lu  Uppercase letter    UPPERCASE_LETTER
Ll  Lowercase letter    LOWERCASE_LETTER
Lt  Titlecase letter    TITLECASE_LETTER
Lm  Modifier letter     MODIFIER_LETTER
Lo  Other letter        OTHER_LETTER
```

What is `L` in this context?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Taken from this link: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Check the `Unicode Character Properties` section.

> \p{L} matches a single code point in
>   the category "letter". If your input
>   string is à encoded as U+0061 U+0300,
>   it matches a without the accent. If
>   the input is à encoded as U+00E0, it
>   matches à with the accent. The reason
>   is that both the code points U+0061
>   (a) and U+00E0 (à) are in the category
>   "letter", while U+0300 is in the
>   category "mark".

Comment: Thanks and +1 to you, too. Your comment on my comment/question to @Ned Batchelder's answer is appreciated.

Comment: For an "official" reference to the "L" category, see here: http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#General_Category_Property

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any explicit mention of it, but an example on [this page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) indicates that `\\p{L}` means any letter:

> Categories may be specified with the optional prefix Is: Both \p{L} and \p{IsL} denote the category of Unicode letters.

Comment: That's what I thought, too, but then why does the following regex replace (with a space) **everything** that's **not** a letter? `String.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}]", " ")`

Comment: @uTubeFan: See you are using *negation* in `^\\p{L}`. So when I do something like this `"Test akd ^^%!~+_)".replaceAll("[^\\p{L}]", " ")` then it will output `Test akd         `. On the contrary if you do something like this `"Test akd ^^%!~+_)".replaceAll("[\\p{L}]", " ");` then the output will be `         ^^%!~+_)`

Comment: @Favonius Thanks! So, can I conclude from this that `^%!~+_` are **not** considered letters? (I am basically looking to replace all non-letters (except apostrophe `'` as in `wasn't`) with a space, any suggestion?)

Comment: @uTubeFan: Just saw your previous comment. Anyway you saved the work for me :)