# How do I validate in js that a string only contains chars from multiple unicode ranges

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, internationalization

**I have an input field and I want to validate that the input is valid for multiple languages (and digits).**

I've gathered some bits from the web but couldn't figure out how to combine these pieces into one working regex.

From [here](http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block) I found some of the ranges I need:

```
0000-007F   Basic Latin
0080-00FF   Latin-1 Supplement
0100-017F   Latin Extended-A
0180-024F   Latin Extended-B
```

From [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0aaa8625-dbb7-417c-8dd8-794e404a7ebb/unicode-range-for-chinese-and-japanese-characters) I found the Japanese range:

```
4e00-9fbf, 3040-309f and 30a0-30ff
```

But how do I combine them to one regex (including digits) in javascript so I can validate that they are the only characters allowed? (I need more languages but if I need to understand the concept and then I can add more unicode ranges myself)

Comment: I think instead of using regex, you can check char by char if any of them are out of range or not.

Comment: 1. how do I do it? 2. Isn't it wrong practice to make validation char by char and not using regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [regex category `\p{L}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969440/what-is-the-l-unicode-category) for you, which matches letter from all known language. But sadly JavaScript's built-in `RegExp` dosen't support it. Instead, you can consider using [`XRegExp`](http://xregexp.com/) with [Unicode Base plugin](http://xregexp.com/plugins/#unicode).

```
<script src="xregexp.js"></script>
<script src="addons/unicode/unicode-base.js"></script>
<script>
  var unicodeWord = XRegExp("^\\p{L}+$");

  unicodeWord.test("Русский"); // true
  unicodeWord.test("日本語"); // true
  unicodeWord.test("العربية"); // true
</script>
```

Code snippet from http://xregexp.com/plugins

Comment: I've seen this library but got confused on how do I concatenate several languages (german, french, spanish, korean, japanese etc) and digits. How would I do such a thing?