# What does regex pattern "[\\P{L}]+" mean in Java?

Tags: java, regex

Code:

```
Arrays.asList("AAAA DDDD, DDDD".split("[\\P{L}]+")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
AAAA
DDDD
DDDD
```

Please notice it's `P{L}` instead of `p{L}`(which means letters). I googled it but find nothing. So could any one give me some hint about that?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969440/what-is-the-l-unicode-category)  for a link to the site where this topic is described thoroughly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can find the explanation in [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) Javadoc:

> Unicode scripts, blocks, categories and binary properties are written with the `\p` and `\P` constructs as in Perl. `\p{prop}` matches if the input has the property prop, while `\P{prop}` does not match if the input has that property.

So it's the opposite of `\p`.

Answer (score 7):

Simple: it's the opposite of `\\p{L}`.

Essentially all "non-letters".

I couldn't find an **exact** reference in the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), but you can infer the suggestion from the behavior or, say, `\\s` vs `\\S` (which **is** documented there).

**Edit** (credit to [Tunaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1743880/tunaki) for having eyes)

This is actually suggested by the following statement in the documentation:

> Unicode blocks and categories are written with the \p and \P
>   constructs as in Perl.

Comment: Is there any doc or reference about that?

Comment: @Sayakiss Tons of this all over the Internet, actually. http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html: *You can match a single character belonging to the "letter" category with `\p{L}`. You can match a single character not belonging to that category with `\P{L}`.*