# What are pZ and pC in unicode?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have found such snippet to remove unicode spaces from string. But what are pZ and pC?

```
preg_replace('/[\pZ\pC]/u', ' ', $price);
```

Comment: [Unicode categories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969440/what-is-the-l-unicode-category). [*`\p{Z}` or `\p{Separator}`: any kind of whitespace or invisible separator.... `\p{C}` or `\p{Other}`: invisible control characters and unused code points.*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Comment: Great answer, thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166896/trim-unicode-whitespace-in-php-5-2 also has some more info.